# VueJS - trigger Modal from materializecss

Tags: materialize, vuejs2

I am trying to trigger a modal from the materializecss framework within a VueJS-instance.

Both, `VueJS` and `Materializecss`, are implemented correct. On their own both frameworks work fine.

Clicking the open-button results in an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: data[option] is not a function
>       at HTMLDivElement. (adminarea.js:24562)
>       at Function.each (adminarea.js:10567)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.each (adminarea.js:10356)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.Plugin [as modal] (adminarea.js:24556)
>       at Vue$3.showLoader (adminarea.js:21396)
>       at boundFn (adminarea.js:54956)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (adminarea.js:56467)

This is my Vue-Instance:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        activeUser: {
            username: '',
            email: ''
        },
    },
    methods: {
        showLoader(){
            $('#loaderModal').modal('open');
        },
        closeLoader(){
            $('#loaderModal').modal('close');
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        // Get current User
        axios.get('/api/currentUser')
            .then(response => {
                this.activeUser.username = response.data.username;
                this.activeUser.email = response.data.email;
            });
    },
    components: {
        Admindashboard
    }
});
```

And here is the part of my html-file with the modal structure:

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
            <div id="loaderModal" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <h4>Fetching data..</h4>
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="indeterminate"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn cyan waves-effect waves-cyan" v-on:click="showLoader">Open</button>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not..

Comment: I can add that i solved mine, but I use a different css framework. In my instance it was the js modules of the css framework that needed to be imported (for that specific module) and applied to the jQuery variable. I don't know if the case is the same for you, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @d00dle can you give an example? I get the idea but have no clue how to solve this..

Comment: I use $.fn.modal = require(<NPM-PACKAGE-FOR-MODAL>) in my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found an solution:

Nice to know for Laravel-users: for my current project I use Laravel 5.5 with Materializecss, VueJS and VueRouter but I think the solution is universal. Materializecss was installed via npm and has to be included into your application. I've required the css-framework within my `ressources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`:

```
...// more code
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.materialize = require('materialize-css');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
...// more code
```

Now you have to initialize the Modal-function on the mounted-event of your wrapping Vue-instance:

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    data: {
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        testClick: function(){
            console.log('Testklick-Call');
            $('#modal1').modal('open');
        }
    },
    mounted: function(){
        console.log('Instance mounted');
        $('.modal').modal();
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

The code above is placed within my `ressources/assets/js/app.js` and is packed by default by [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/frontend) but I think this is universal and also usable without Laravel Mix/Webpack etc.

Now you can call every modal programmatically from where ever you want. I've tested it in my main instance on a click-event. Function is placed in my Vue-instance (see above). HTML-Code see below:

```
<button v-on:click="testClick">Open Modal</button>
```

But you can also make use of the modal within a mounted-function or any other function of any component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>I am an component!</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted!');
            $('#modal1').modal('open');
        }
    }
</script>
```

This also works, if the component becomes only visible after clicked on a link (using VueRouter).

Hopefully this helps someone except me :)

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for 4 dayssssss. Thank you so much. And for all Laravel + Vue users, this is the way you can truly load Materialize.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](http://materializecss.com/modals.html), you need to add following code in the mounted block:

```
mounted() {
    $('#loaderModal').modal();  //New line to be added
    // Get current User
    axios.get('/api/currentUser')
        .then(response => {
            this.activeUser.username = response.data.username;
            this.activeUser.email = response.data.email;
        });
},
```

Comment: Now the modal pops up on mounted event. But I want the modal to pop up on click.. Also the error changed to: `Uncaught TypeError: data[option] is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (adminarea.js:24525)
    at Function.each (adminarea.js:10567)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (adminarea.js:10356)
    at jQuery.fn.init.Plugin [as modal] (adminarea.js:24519)
    at Vue$3.showLoader (adminarea.js:21396)
    at boundFn (adminarea.js:54852)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (adminarea.js:56363)`